# Passing my own Classes to Objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, object

I have a function `WriteList` that saves a list into a file. This function has the parameter `List<Object>` so I can pass different types of Lists as parameter.

```
    public void WriteList(List<object> input, string ListName)
    {
        WriteToFile("List - " + ListName);
        foreach (object temp in input)
        {
            WriteToFile(temp.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When calling this function from my code I want to pass the parameter `List<Database>` where `Database` is my own made class. I get the following error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List -Database-' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List-object-'

So my question is how to convert my own class to an Object, and then pass a list to my function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`List<T>` is not [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). Use `IEnumerable<T>` instead:

```
public void WriteList(IEnumerable<object> input, string ListName)
{
    WriteToFile("List - " + ListName);
    foreach (object temp in input)
    {
        WriteToFile(temp.ToString());
    }
}
```

Or make the method generic:

```
public void WriteList<T>(List<T> input, string ListName)
{
    WriteToFile("List - " + ListName);
    foreach (T temp in input)
    {
        WriteToFile(temp.ToString());
    }
}
```

IMO: The second one is better, because there is no boxing/unboxing when used with value types.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq:

```
List<object> objectList = myList.Cast<object>().ToList();
this.WriteList(objectList, "Some Name")
```

Don't forget to import linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<Database>` is not castable to `List<object>`. One way is to declare your `List<Database>` class as `List<Object>`, note: you are still able to add **Database** objects to it.